# How to call chinese text from XML to flash?

Tags: xml, flash, cjk

I am trying to get Chinese text using XML file. it's loading text BUT it doesn't display Chinese text in it, It only displays Square/Box. I have used TAHOMA font for that text box. is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to embed font if the system don't have the Chinese font. Select the dynamic text which you want for display the text. Select embed font and choose the char set you needed.

Or, you can set the dynamic text to device font to display the Chinese char. But, if the user did not have Chinese font, they can,t be displayed.

P.s. Make sure your Chinese text within the XML is in uincode.

Comment: Hi WaiLam, This works. Thanks a lot!

I only changed the text property as "device font" and I didn't required to use uincode. Chinese text within the XML works fine.